# Найти склеенные предложения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть файл, в нем предложения — по одному на строку. Но при этом попадаются склеенные предложения (во второй строке — предложение, начинающееся с «The first»).

> It is a unique and creative way to make family photos.
>   Subject in different placesThe first step is taking the images you will use.
>   In the second one she gets ready to hit it back.

Мне нужно найти предложения, в которых после маленькой буквы сразу идет большая, а затем сразу маленькая (т.е., вторая строка в примере). И затем разложить нормальные предложения и склеенные по разным файлам.

```
$lines = file('text.txt');

foreach($lines as $line){

if (preg_match("#^(регулярка)$#i", $line))
file_put_contents('ok.txt', $line, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
else
file_put_contents('err.txt', $line, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

}
```

Помогите с регуляркой.

Comment: А что такое "Предложение", можно было бы предположить, что предложения разделены точками, но это не так, могут быть сокращения в которых точки в середине. Кроме того условие маленькая-большая-маленькая то же не корректно. Никто не мешает предложению начинаться единственной большой буквой, например 'I' и если оно будет склеено то будет маленькая-большая-пробел. А еще обычное предложение может заканчиваться на аббревиатуру большими буквами ...

Comment: Предложения в файле разделены символом переноса строки \n

Comment: Ну т.е. вам тупо строки где есть маленькая-большая-маленькая. Неужели сами не догадаетесь. 3 минуты чтения статьи на вики по регуляркам достаточно что бы написать `/[a-z][A-Z][a-z]/`, даже если их увидели впервые в жизни

Comment: `My name is Rein I am lamer` Разве не бывает однобуквенных слов?

Answer (score 1):

> после маленькой буквы сразу идет большая, а затем сразу маленькая

если буквы ограничиваются только латинским алфавитом, то достаточно такого регулярного выражения:

```
[a-z][A-Z][a-z]
```

если такого ограничения нет (т.е., могут встретиться буквы из других алфавитов), то лучше воспользоваться [символьными классами](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.character-classes.php):

```
[:lower:][:upper:][:lower:]
```